# How to creative a responsive chessboard

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive chessboard that is mobile friendly and changes size when the window is minimized but i cant seem to get rid of this space between the inner div colors and outer div sqaure. No idea what i am doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <p></p>
  <div class="square">

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.square {
  border: 10px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vw;    
  margin: auto;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 11.5%;
  width:  11.5%;
  max-height: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  float: left;    
  padding:0;
  margin:auto;

}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 11.5%;
  width:  11.5%;
  max-height: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  float: left; 
  padding:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: % or vW are not going to help you. Why don't you try JS? do everything based on width and everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a problem with your maths. You're giving each square a width of 11.5%, which adds up to 92%. Should be 12.5% to add up to 100% (i.e. the full width of the container).

```css
.square {
  border: 10px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 12.5%;
  width: 12.5%;
  max-height: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 12.5%;
  width: 12.5%;
  max-height: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p></p>
  <div class="square">

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <!--2nd -->
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <!--2nd -->
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4d7vubv/)